# All I get is "Client/Server JS Editor"

Tags: eclipse, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

In XPages, when I try to open a .js or .jss file, I often get just the tab wirh "Client/Server JS Editor" and nothing else, i.e. the file doesn't load. From the Navigator Eclipse view, I can open the same .js or .jss file using any other editor without problems. And then, it sometimes works, but I don't know yet when it does and when it doesn't. The other Editors are okay by the way, .lss opens nicely.

This behaviour I get for a few weeks now. Since it started I reinstalled Notes a few times, I upgraded to FP8, I also reinstalled Windows10 and Windows10 upgraded me to the Creators Update (with the fix, in the end). There's nothing that explains to me why the file doesn't show up on the screen.

Anyone familiar with this? Could you please tell me how to repair this?

Thanks!!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [bug introduced with FP8](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg22000221) that is fixed in FP8 Interim Fix 1. See [this document](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963) for download options for FP8 IF1.

As a workaround you can do a clean/rebuild of the nsf and then use the SSJS editor.

Comment: It sometimes works, even without the clean rebuild. Downloading IF1 shortly... Thanks!